# EasyOCR script run error - No module named 'torch.backends'

Tags: python, ocr

how to deal with such error during script run? Easyocr installed in the new env

```
File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\easyocr\detection.py", line 2, in <module>
    import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn    


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.backends'
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/4827

Comment: yes, I've seen this one, but solutions there does not help. I've installed pytorch vis this command:
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch

Comment: OK, I've noticed couple things:
1. I'm running my script from spyder and I have several environments setup. 1 specifically to run my script.
2. In the custom environment there were no spyder installed, so my script was executed from base environment interpreter and therefore got error from that custom environment.
3. So now I've figure out how to run spyder from specific environment, so current issue is gone. but there is another one related to CUDA memory issues now

Answer (score 1):

Solved with `pip3 install torchvision==0.6`, this will install torch 1.5.0 as a dependency automatically.
currently easyocr neither working on the latest 1.11.0 version of torch, nor the 1.4.0 version of torch.